# based on some condition we have to change the joining table

Tags: db2

I'm facing one problem. I'm creating one proc like Temp_district.

In that there is a requirement like based on some condition we have to change the joining table.

```
like if(year=2016) then 
select * from table1 a join table2 b  on (a.id=b.id) join table3 c on (c.id=b.id) join table4 d on d.id=a.id


if(year<>2016) then
select * from table1 a join table2 b  on (a.id=b.id) join table3 c on (c.id=b.id) join table5 e on d.id=a.id;
```

query is almost same and is too much big query, in that only one table is getting changed if year is not 2016 here i.e table4 to table5

Is there any thing like below

```
if(year=2016) then 
with temp_table_2016 (select * from table4)
else with temp_table_2016 (select * from table6)
```

so that in single query I can replace that table4 or table5 with temp_table_2016, based on condition it will fetch data from required table.

Comment: The solution will depend on which database you are using.

Comment: You're facing this problem in four different database systems ?

Comment: i'm facing the problem in DB2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So just join both with an opposite condition:

```
SELECT t.*,
        COALESCE(t4.col,t5.col) as col,
        COALESCE(t4.col2,t5.col2) as col2,
       ....
FROM t
LEFT JOIN t4 ON(t.id = t4.id AND year = 2016)
LEFT JOIN t5 ON(t.id = t5.id AND year <> 2016)
```

You'll need to add `COALESCE()` on all the tables columns , so only the corresponding data will appear. If you don't care, you can select them both and 1 of them will always be `NULL` .

Comment: Thank you so much ... solution is working fine ... once again thank you

Comment: one more doubt, if that varying table is first table then what is the solution for it... plz help.

Comment: @RameshYelda Use a dummy table then.. `SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1 as Dummy_Col)  Dummy_Table LEFT JOIN Varying_Table_1 ON(Year = 2016) ... LEFT JOIN Varying_Table_2 ON (YEAR<>2016)...`

Answer (score 0):

You may use achieve it like this if you are using MSSQL:

```
DECLARE @secondtable NVARCHAR(20)

if(year=2016)
BEGIN
SET @secondtable = 'table4'
END

if(year<>2016)
BEGIN
SET @secondtable = 'table5'
END



EXEC('select * from table1 a join table2 b
 on (a.id=b.id) join table3 c on (c.id=b.id) join '+@secondtable+' d on d.id=a.id')
```